# Ansible failed to connect to the host via ssh Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ssh, ansible

I am working with Ansible plugin on Jenkins and I had the next error:

```yaml
> "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Load key \"/etc/ansible/jenkinsPem\": Permission denied\r\nmadchabelo@targethost: Permission denied (publickey,password).", "unreachable": true}
```

my hosts file:

```yaml
[targets]
targethost ansible_user=madchabelo ansible_private_key_file=/etc/ansible/jenkinsPem
mysqlhost ansible_user=madchabelo ansible_private_key_file=/etc/ansible/jenkinsPem
```

My playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Playbook for jenkins
  hosts: [targets]
  tasks:
   - name: hello world
     shell: echo Hello World again
```

But if I run on shell:

```yaml
ansible-playbook -i /etc/ansible/hosts /etc/ansible/playbook/jenkinsansible.yaml
```

All its good:

```yaml
PLAY [Playbook for jenkins] *******************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************
[WARNING]: Platform linux on host targethost is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python3, but future installation of another Python interpreter
could change this. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information.

ok: [targethost]

[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Distribution fedora 36 on host mysqlhost should use /usr/bin/python3, but is using /usr/bin/python for backward compatibility with prior Ansible
 releases. A future Ansible release will default to using the discovered platform python for this host. See 
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information. This feature will be removed in version 2.12. Deprecation 
warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.

ok: [mysqlhost]

TASK [hello world] ***************************************************
changed: [targethost]
changed: [mysqlhost]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************
mysqlhost: ok=2  changed=1  unreachable=0  failed=0  skipped=0  rescued=0  ignored=0   
targethost: ok=2 changed=1  unreachable=0  failed=0  skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Here are the paths on Jenkins:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The private key should be stored in the Jenkins credentials.
The plugin [ssh-credentials](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-credentials/) should be installed in Jenkins.
Then:

```yaml
Manage Jenkins ==> Manage Credentials ==> add credentials ==> SSH username with private key
```

Give it an `ID`,`username`,paste the key in the `Private Key` section and save it.
[image]
In the `Build steps` shown on the screenshot in your question, there should be the option `Credentials` under the inventory option (It may not exsist because the ssh-credentials plugin isn't installed).
The saved credentials should be found there to be chosen.
[image: Jenkins screenshot]
The playbook should now be executed without any problem.